# Java Perl Bug when running batch on mssql

Tags: java, sql-server

Java Perl Bug when        running batch on mssql'
Developers 19y old code...
Cmd prompt ex:

```
C:\batch>Rem Run Java program which notifies by email.

C:\batch>set CLASSPATH=PerlTools.jar;.;mail.jar;activation.jar;SIMP_Components.jar;sqljdbc.jar

C:\batch>java Notify notify\report5.txt
Writing to file notify\report5.txt
Fetching notifications.
Done with fetching notifications.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler tried to access private field com.oroinc.text.regex.CharStringPointer.__offset (com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler and com.oroinc.text.regex.CharStringPointer are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler._getNextChar(Perl5Compiler.java)
        at com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler._parseAlternation(Perl5Compiler.java)
        at com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler._parseExpression(Perl5Compiler.java)
        at com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler.compile(Perl5Compiler.java)
        at com.oroinc.text.perl.Perl5Util.__compilePatterns(Perl5Util.java)
        at com.oroinc.text.perl.Perl5Util.<init>(Perl5Util.java)

        at se.lazybee.simp.SIMP_StoredProcedure.addString(SIMP_StoredProcedure.java:88)
        at Notify.main(Notify.java:195)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl. It's a problem with a Java library, `com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler`. (I happens to implements support for regex supposedly matching Perl's regex syntax, but that's not relevant to the problem.)

Comment: =? -so how FIX shown error?

Comment: It looks like in the bug in the module to me, but I haven't used Java in 20 years.

Comment: ...heh, I just noticed you said it's 19 year old code. I presume the newer version of Java strengthened some checks or added restrictions that weren't there 19 years ago. You might need a newer `com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler` (or an older `java.exe`)

Comment: thxs. how to  do it?

Comment: ikegami  writes 'You might need a newer com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler' where/how?

Comment: You're asking me where you got the module???

Comment: ikegami  writes 'You might need a newer com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Compiler' where/how? = the  code/modules we have are AS SAID  19 years old - so  where/how get newer ORO / file ‘perltools.jar’ IS in dir batch… Maybe Outdated??
several of our  Java files contains ‘import com.oroinc.text.perl.Perl5Util; ‘

Class com.oroinc.text.perl.Perl5Util
java.lang.Object
   |
   +----com.oroinc.text.perl.Perl5Util
The objective of the class is to minimize the amount of code a Java programmer using OROMatcherTM has to write to achieve the same results as Perl… says www.savarese.org